# Broadcast event when state loaded and controllers are initiated

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to broadcast an event when state is fully loaded and controllers are initiated. I'm using AngularJS v1.3.15 and ui-router v0.2.11.

I'm trying to use `$stateChangeSuccess` event, but the controller doesn't grab the broadcasted event, because it hasn't been iniatated when the event is broadcasted.

In my module `run` method I have:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent');
});
```

My controller has the following:

```
$scope.$on('someEvent', function () {
    $scope.getList();
});
```

I tried using `$viewContentLoading` and `$viewContentLoaded` but because I have nested controllers/views, it fires multiple times, so `$scope.getList()` runs multiple times.

Any solution to this problem?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish once the controllers have been initiated?

Comment: @Rob Get data from a server.

Comment: Then just make an http request from one of your controllers.  It won't make the call until the controller has been loaded.

Comment: @Rob I know, but I'm using the same `getList()` method when the user changes his company. That's why I'm broadcasting an event, catching it and then running `getList()`

Comment: Without seeing more of your code it's hard to really understand how this works.  A stab in the dark would be to broadcast your event in the callback of your getList function.

Comment: I have a fairly large application where super users can switch to other companies and get data for that company. In each controller, I catch `someEvent` and then run `getList()`. What I have been using is `$viewContentLoaded` but with nested views, it gets fired multiple times and that's no good. That's why I tried `$stateChangeSuccess` - but the controller isn't initiated when the event is broadcasted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by catching the `someEvent` error and call the `$scope.getList()` method, but also calling the `$scope.getList()` method when the controller is initiated (at the bottom in the controller).

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is no need to put a stateChange listener.
angular ui-router provide a feature for your use case: resolving a controller on state change see [ui-router on github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).
Further more you should use a service returning a promise, since your api call is async, and then inject the service in the controller. See the "resolve" section on the same page that answers your needs.

Comment: Not sure if that's good enough. When changing a company, I fire this event, which retrieves the data for that company from the server. I have to use events.